# How to fix (Cannot use $this as parameter in /Timber/functions/functions-twig.php on line 214)

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

> Fatal error: Cannot use $this as parameter in /www/webvol14/pn/nlr3fq63bvk0q48/skywork.se/public_html/wp-content/themes/startup/vendor/Timber/functions/functions-twig.php on line 214

Site: php 7.1

```
/**
 * @param mixed $this
 * @return string
 */
function twig_get_class($this) {
    return get_class($this);
}

/**
 * @param mixed $this
 * @return string
 */
function twig_get_type($this) {
    return gettype($this);
}
```

Comment: is `$this` not a reserved keyword?

Comment: @treyBake indeed $this is a reserved keyword!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the php manual:

> Warning Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's
>   Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods. The variable
>   $this is also a special variable that cannot be referenced
>   dynamically.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php#120071